# Node.js play-sound: TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, undefined, typeerror

Trying to play a notification sound using the Node.js package play-sound.
However, when trying to do so, I get this error:
"Node.js play-sound: TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined"

```
  const player = require('play-sound')(opts = {});


  start() {
    this.player.play('/sounds/throughQueue.mp3', function(err){
                            if (err) throw err
                            })
  }
```

This is what my program looks like if I cut out all the other stuff.
Yes, I've installed the play-sound package.

I'm not experienced with JS and Node, if there's any info missing or if there's another package you'd recommend to play a simple notification sound, please let me know!

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: `this.player` doesn't exist.

Comment: To add to SLaks comment, from your snippet it looks like you should access the `player` variable directly, not via `this`. EG: `player.play()` and not `this.player.play()`

Comment: Show more code....

Comment: Thanks to both of you, fixed it, got another error but managed to fix that. Now it's working. I really appreciate the fast replies! Haven't used JavaScript before and tried to modify an open source program. Can I somehow mark this question/thread as answered?

Comment: @ZenoFox You can only mark the question as answered if there is an answer in the Answers section. I wrote [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47761288/578288) below, so you can accept it to mark the question as resolved (see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)). If you ever learn the solution from the comments but nobody writes an actual answer, you can [write an answer to your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept that answer. That would help future people with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [CRice said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761179/node-js-play-sound-typeerror-cannot-read-property-play-of-undefined#comment82483686_47761179), refer to the defined `player` variable with `player`, not `this.player`:

```js
const player = require('play-sound')(opts = {});

start() {
    player.play('/sounds/throughQueue.mp3', function(err){
        if (err) throw err
    })
}
```